# How to group combinations of values that may intersect with each other more than once?

Tags: r, dataframe, intersection

I am trying to track the intersection of several values in a dataframe. However, one value may intersect with more than one value and these different intersections may be located in different rows.

Consider the following dataframe created by the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "G", "H"),
  col2 = c("B", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "H", "B")
)
```

That is:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| D | C |
| D | D |
| D | E |
| D | F |
| G | H |
| H | B |

From such a dataframe, I would like to know how to create a new one in which:

1. Every unique value, be it in `col1` or in `col2`, becomes a row.
2. A variable in a new column is created assigning a unique code for all values that somehow intersect with each other in the original dataframe.

The expected dataframe would look like the following:

| value | code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 2 |
| G | 1 |
| H | 1 |

The logic is: A, B, G and H have the same code because of A-B, B-A, G-H and H-B. Thus, if H is related to B and to G and B is related to A, then all four values A, B, G and H are related. The same logic should apply for all values.

I tried several things and none of them worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a graph theory problem - you can think of each of your values as a node of a graph, and if they occur in the same row then there is an edge connecting the nodes. Your goal is to list the connected subgraphs - or clusters.

```
library(igraph)
df |>
  as.matrix() |>
  graph_from_edgelist() |>
  clusters() |>
  getElement("membership") |>
  stack()
#   values ind
# 1      1   A
# 2      1   B
# 3      2   D
# 4      2   C
# 5      2   E
# 6      2   F
# 7      1   G
# 8      1   H
```